# How to Test if a file has characters in it?

Tags: shell-script, files, test

So i have a part of this code and U want it to output "No such player" if only the names file is empty, i've tried using the test -s command but it gives an output of 0 even if the file is empty or not. how would i go about solving this issue.

```
       if [ $Target = m -o $Target = M ]
       then
       cut -c12-26,31-43 ./emplist > names
       grep $Name ./names
       if
       **[ -s  names ]**
       then
          :
       else
       echo "No such player"
       fi
```

Basically i want it to output the names w.o outputting " no such player" if there are names in the file. and out put " no such players" if there are no names in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ "$Target" = m ] || [ "$Target" = M ];
then
   cut -c12-26,31-43 emplist > names
fi
if grep -qFe "$name" names; then
  echo "$name"
else
  echo >&2 "No such player";
fi
```